# How to get current Modal window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, modal-dialog, prism

In my project I have a Mainwindow. In that mainwindow there is a button to open the modal window. In that Modal window there is a button to open another modal window in the same view. I have used Keybinding for closing the modal window. When two modal window is opened condition when I pressed the escape key background model window is first closed. I have to close the current window. Please anyone suggest me to done this.

**ShellWindow**

```
<Grid>
   <Grid>
       <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="SessionView" />
  </Grid>
  <Grid>
      <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="AddNewSessionView" />
   </Grid>
</Grid>
```

In Shell window there is a button to open the "SessionView" Modal window. In the SessionView there is a one button to open the "AddNewSessionView" Modal window. Both are registered in Shell window. When AddNewSessionView is opened condition, when I click the esc button the Background SessionView is closed first.

Comment: Can you show some code? I guess you're having your key bindings on mainwindow and that here the order of key bindings might be the issue.

Comment: @Jan, Please see my updated code.

Comment: Have you tried setting the owner of the modal window? the code of the buttons would be helpful

Comment: @Jan, No I have not set Owner of the modal window. How to set the owner of the modal window in prism. Please give any suggestion.

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660684/wpfprism-how-to-make-the-popup-window-owner-as-main-window  
I'm no prism expert so without seeing more code, I cannot help